# 404 error while running web-app using Struts on tomcat in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, http-status-code-404, struts

I am a beginner to web development using struts. I have followed an online tutorial into making a web-app using Struts in Eclipse. The link of the tutorial is 
    http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/struts/struts-tutorial/struts-tutorial-using-eclipse-1.html where the source code is available. When i start the server and run the application , i get 404 page not found error despite i feel like i have done things properly. I have attached the error page i get. [image]

Also I have checked logs for errors, but it doesn't give me any information apart from this
[image]

So can anyone please help me find out why isn't the app working?

struts-config file
[image]

Comment: Can you show us your struts-config file?

Comment: @BelgianMyWaffle: I have attached it, please take a look

Comment: Post your code as text, not as images. And why are you learning a framework that is officially dead?

Comment: @JBNizet: It says the text is too long to post as a comment. We are using struts in my company so thats why i am beginning to learn it. Is struts officially dead and so no use in learning it?

Comment: @JBNizet: Also i am just beginning out with web development using java. I do not know what should i learn so that i master in web development so can you please guide me in the sense what framework should be learnt?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `HelloWorlAction.class` and `HelloWorldForm.class`.

In struts you just need an action class and form class with a java extension.

So you only need:

```
HelloWorlAction.java
HelloWorlActionForm.java
```

Comment: Okay thanks I have removed it. But it doesn't seem to have any effect because i get the same 404 error on running once again!

Comment: Did you add 

`</welcome-file-list><welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>` to your web.xml?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting errors 404 if you use `/HelloWorld` in the context path of your application. Either you have deployed to the wrong path or this path doesn't exist. Try to remove it from the URL. Also in the tutorial you have mentioned it's not used. The url

```
http://localhost:8080/StrutsExample1/helloWorld.do
```

Comment: I have tried using the path but it doesn't work! I just don't understand, how can the deployment path not exist??

Comment: Check your webapps folder if you have such path or not, if not then it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to start again calling your project "StrutsExample1" and leaving please WebContent as it is. Follow strictly that tutorial and you will get what you're expecting.

After doing that please use the correct path as suggested by Roman C:

```
http://localhost:8080/StrutsExample1/helloWorld.do
```

Also you could use this header in web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
            xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
            id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
```

if you are using modern containers as Tomcat 7.
Let me know, regards

Comment: Ya i have tried doing this but the error persists.And then ya i use Tomcat7. Has it got anything to do with the error?

Comment: There are no problems with the project, I assure you. I tried to set it up and I made it. So I suggest you to restart from scratch and be very careful to do exactly what it's stated in the tutorial. I see in your first screenshot that you messed things up

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `apache-commons.jar` and `servlet-api.jar` to your Java build path (Libraries section in `Eclipse`). It solved my 404 problem.